# Ruby Datetime Error no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am testing Datetime (ruby) with null value and am getting the error "TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String". I wonder why my code is not working accordingly if it already has exception implemented. Any explanation about this or how to get rid of it?

```
      def get_parsed_datetime(raw_payload)
        parse_datetime(raw_payload[:datetime])
      rescue ArgumentError
        raise Base::UnprocessableContentError, I18n.t('invalid_datetime_error')
      end

      def parse_datetime(datetime_value)
        {
          :date => Date.parse(datetime_value).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),
          :hour => Time.parse(datetime_value).hour
        }
      end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `Date.parse(nil)` and `Time.parse(nil)` will raise `TypeError`.

`get_parsed_datetime` only rescues `ArgumentError`, and not `TypeError`.

A version that also rescues for `TypeError` would look like this:

```rb
def get_parsed_datetime(raw_payload)
  parse_datetime(raw_payload[:datetime])
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
  raise Base::UnprocessableContentError, I18n.t('invalid_datetime_error')
end
```

or, a version that rescues all types of errors could `rescue StandardError`.